Web View 2: navigation error connecting to Blazor server app
I've been using WV2 for a couple of years to connect customers to my site.
Recently I've been getting navigation failure 500 errors with Status code "Unknown" in my CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted handler. Customers can't connect to the landing page on my site although the page loads fine with same query string in Firefox/Edge and Chrome.
I can also complete test purchases both on IIS and the remote server so it looks as though the issue is WV2 specific. I'm running WV2 1.0.2365.46 on Net8 and the site is a Blazor server app.
It's not an anti-virus issue as customers report they still can't connect with av switched off.
Any insights much appreciated.
